# Android Views: Getting a view to snap to the left hand side of the screen

Tags: android, view, gravity

I have 2 views one is a scroll view and the other is a LinearLayout.  I want the LinearLayout to be a fixed size, i have it about 80dp.  I want this layout to be on the right hand side of my screen the whole time.  The rest of the space i want my Scroll View to take up. Here is what my code looks like.

```
     <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/widget4327"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#F4F5DC">


<ScrollView 
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_below="@+id/line">

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearL2"
    android:background="#EEEFE0"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ScrollView01">

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I thought the gravity would take care of this but i cant seem to get it working.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a `RelativeLayout` then you can set the `alignToParentLeft` to true

Comment: Hi VNVN,  Thanks for your response.  This makes the view shift to the left of the screen but sometimes the scrollview pushes the view off the screen.  Is there any way to make the view stay on the screen and just shrink the scrollview?

Comment: i got it just made the ScrollView have a right margin that is the same size of the view.  Thanks